# Add Attribute to all child Elements using apply-templates

Tags: xml, xslt

I try to add an attribute web to all child elements of the element web by using apply-template.

source xml

```
<p></p>
<tabel>
 <tr>
  <td>
   <web>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
   </web>
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>
   <web>
    <p></p>
    <ul>
     <li></li>
     <li></li>
    </ul> 
   </web>
  </td>
 </tr>
</tabel>
```

target xml

```
<p></p>
<tabel>
 <tr>
  <td>
   <p class="web"></p>
   <p class="web"></p>
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>
   <p class="web"></p>
   <ul class="web">
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
   </ul> 
  </td>
 </tr>
</tabel>
```

my xsl

```
<xsl:template match="p">
 <p>
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
 </p>
</xsl:template>   
<xsl:template match="web">
 <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>   
<xsl:template match="ul">
 <ul>
  <xsl:apply-templates/> 
 </ul>
</xsl:template>
```

Is there any possibility to apply-templates and add the attribute web to all child elements of web?
Does anyone have an idea, how to do this?

Comment: The source document that you show us is not well-formed XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a **well-formed** input such as:

**XML**

```
<html>
    <p></p>
    <tabel>
      <tr>
        <td>
        <web>
          <p></p>
          <p></p>
        </web>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
        <web>
          <p></p>
            <ul>
              <li></li>
              <li></li>
            </ul> 
        </web>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tabel>
</html>
```

the following stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" encoding="UTF-8"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="web">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="web/*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:attribute name="class">web</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

will return:

```
<html>
   <p></p>
   <tabel>
      <tr>
         <td>
            <p class="web"></p>
            <p class="web"></p>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>
            <p class="web"></p>
            <ul class="web">
               <li></li>
               <li></li>
            </ul>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </tabel>
</html>
```

---

Note that `tabel` is not a valid HTML element.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, it work’s absolutely perfect.